# How to build a react lib generated by Stencil with NX, for publishing to npm?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, monorepo, stenciljs

I have a **NX monorepo** with **Stencil** setup. I have my stencil web components, and I generate a React library using Stencil. I can use the library in a React app normally in the same repo.

I want now to be able to build the React library to be able to publish it to NPM to be able to import it in other projects.

I tried using Rollup with **@nrwl/web:rollup** to build it, but it only generates a bundle without a package.json file, is there a way to use that for publishing ? I also tried using **@nrwl/web:webpack**, but I can't find the right configuration. What is the right NX executor to use for that ? Webpack and gulp maybe ? How to configure it ?

For the Angualr lib, it was very simple, I just used **@nrwl/angular:package**. I was expecting something similar in React. Please help if you have encountered this issue, or have an idea.

Comment: You can use `npm publish` to publish the bundle according to the package.json properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @nxext/stencil:make-lib-buildable from NX Console if you use it, or CI `nx generate @nxext/stencil:make-lib-buildable your-components-react --style=scss --no-interactive`

Check docs for options like `importPath`

That will create a build object in project.json that looks like;

````
      "executor": "@nrwl/rollup:rollup",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "dependsOn": ["^build"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/packages/your-components-react",
        "tsConfig": "packages/your-components-react/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "packages/your-components-react/package.json",
        "entryFile": "packages/your-components-react/src/index.ts",
        "external": ["react/jsx-runtime"],
        "rollupConfig": "@nrwl/react/plugins/bundle-rollup",
        "generateExportsField": true,
        "skipTypeField": true,
        "format": ["esm", "cjs"],
        "compiler": "babel",
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "packages/your-components-react/README.md",
            "input": ".",
            "output": "."
          }
        ]
      }
    },```

From there you can deploy package with `ngx-deploy-npm` or pipeline or other method.
````